# How to change the return type of an inherited class member

Tags: c++, templates

I've just recently learned about templates and I was a bit curious. Is it possible to change the return type of an inherited function to the template type?

For example:

```
class A{
public:
    int getSomething();
};

template<typename T>
class B : public A{
public:
    T getSomething();
};
```

Comment: Well, no. You can't change the original function definition. If you make `A` or `A::getSomething` a template, you could do something similar. What the code right now does is hide `A::getSomething`, which isn't really changing the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [can do that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c3cdd2575dc9dc5), but the function in `B` will hide the function in `A`. When you use `someB.getSomething()`, only the function in `B` will be seen. This is true regardless of whether the return type matches or not.

You can bring `A::getSomething` into scope if you wish:

```
template<typename T>
class B : public A {
public:
    using A::getSomething;
    T getSomething();
};
```

However, this using declaration is more useful when `A::getSomething` has a different signature, unlike here, where they both have the same parameter list.

To *override* `getSomething` here, it must be marked as `virtual`:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual int getSomething();
};
```

Now, trying to instantiate `B` with something other than `int` [fails to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cdc176979ad411f).

There is still [one case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/516dd423fa4bd282) where you can change the return type and still override the function. This is a **covariant** return type, where the derived class returns something more derived than what the base class returns:

```
class A{
public:
    virtual A* getSomething();
};

class B : public A{
public:
    B* getSomething() override; 
};
```